# Bash echo outputting text in middle of concatenated string

Tags: bash, echo, ubuntu

Preamble:
So I have a project whereby I need to run a conversion tool on a bunch of files. There are multiple steps to the conversion, and it can take a while. Since these files aren't necessarily in the same directory, I created a text file with the filenames to convert:

```
<filenames.txt>

/home/me/Documents/file1.txt
/home/me/Documents/file2.txt
/home/me/Documents/file3.txt
```

Problem:
I then have a bash script to run over these files, and do the conversion steps. However, I try and echo the phase and filename, and echo, in this case, sticks the echo'd text in the middle of the filename:

```
<script.sh>

cat filenames.txt | while read some_file
do
    echo
    echo "Begin FORMAT_A to FORMAT_B conversion..."
    echo "FORMAT_A Filename:"
    echo $some_file
    formatb_dir= dirname $some_file | tr '\n' "/"
    formatb_file= basename $some_file ".xml" | tr '\n' "_"
    formatb=$formatb_dir$formatb_file"form_b.xml\n"

    echo "FORMAT_B Filename:"
    echo $formatb
done
```

Produces output like this:

```
Begin FORMAT_A to FORMAT_B conversion...
FORMAT_A Filename:
/home/me/Documents/file1.txt
/home/me/Documents/file1.txt_FORMAT_B Filename:
form_b.xml


Begin FORMAT_A to FORMAT_B conversion...
FORMAT_A Filename:
/home/me/Documents/file2.txt
/home/me/Documents/file2.txt_FORMAT_B Filename:
form_b.xml


Begin FORMAT_A to FORMAT_B conversion...
FORMAT_A Filename:
/home/me/Documents/file3.txt
/home/me/Documents/file3.txt_FORMAT_B Filename:
form_b.xml
```

"FORMAT_B Filename", the echo'd text, has appeared before the appended text "form_b.xml".

I looked at the man pages for dirname, basename, echo and tr, but I didn't spot anything that looks like it'd cause what I'm seeing. I tried looking around on Google, but I'm not sure I'm asking the right questions ("bash echo text before variable"?).

Question: **Why is my echo putting the echo'd text in the middle of my variable?**

(possible related question: "Am I going about what I'm doing in completely the wrong way?")

**Edit:** I accepted fortea's answer because it walked me through what I didn't understand about variables and getting the output from commands. That said, dogbane and Jonathan Leffler showed better ways of doing what I was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the declaration of variables:

```
formatb_dir= dirname $some_file | tr '\n' "/"
formatb_file= basename $some_file ".xml" | tr '\n' "_"
formatb=$formatb_dir$formatb_file"form_b.xml\n"
```

Try a new line: `echo $formatb_dir`: it does not contain anything because after the '=' there is a blank space. Then bash reads `dirname $somefile |tr '\n' "/"` and it executes this command. The same when you create formatb_file, but this time the command is basename. (this is what appears before "FORMAT_B Filename:").
Then formatb is created correctly, but $formatb_dir and $formatb_file are empty, so $formatb will contain only `"form_b.xml\n"`.
Then you echo "FORMAT_B Filename:".
Then you echo $formatb, which will output "form_b.xml".

So, you should use something like this:

```
formatb_dir=$(dirname $some_file | tr '\n' "/")
formatb_file=$(basename $some_file ".xml" | tr '\n' "_")
formatb=$formatb_dir$formatb_file"form_b.xml\n"
```

Read [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're running commands like `dirname` and `basename` with the environment set in odd ways, rather than capturing the output. That is, if you run:

```
env_var=some_value commandname arg1 arg2
```

The program `commandname` is run with the environment variable `$env_var` set to `some_value` (for this command only).  In your code, you wrote:

```
formatb_dir= dirname $some_file | tr '\n' "/"
```

This is isomorphic with the example I gave.  It runs the command `dirname` with the environment variable `formatb_dir` set to an empty string (and `dirname` completely ignores this), then sends the output of `dirname` to `tr` and the output of `tr` to standard output.

- No spaces around assignments in shell
- Use `$(...)` to capture output.
- Do not embed newlines in file names; it will make life hell!

I wouldn't bother with mapping the newline at the end of the `dirname` output into a slash, or the one at the end of the `basename` output into an underscore.  You can add the slash and underscore in the generated name.

Fixed:

```
cat filenames.txt |
while read some_file
do
    echo
    echo "Begin FORMAT_A to FORMAT_B conversion..."
    echo "FORMAT_A Filename:"
    echo $some_file
    formatb_dir=$(dirname "$some_file")
    formatb_file=$(basename "$some_file" ".xml")
    formatb="${formatb_dir}/${formatb_file}_form_b.xml"
    echo "FORMAT_B Filename:"
    echo $formatb
done
```

The assignment for `formatb` uses `${varname}` twice for consistency; the braces are only necessary around the `${formatb_file}` expansion.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `tr` and removing the `\n` character.

Instead of using `tr`, why not simply concatenate the strings together?

```
formatb_dir="$(dirname ${some_file})"
formatb_file="$(basename ${some_file})"
formatb="${formatb_dir}/${formatb_file}_form_b.xml"
echo "FORMAT_B Filename: $formatb"
```